# "First come, first serve(d)"

Tags: idioms

What is the correct version of this common phrase?

> 1. First come, first **serve**
> 2. First come, first **served**

Gramatically, I believe 2. is the correct form. However, it seems that 1. is commonly employed in spoken and even written English.

Comment: "First come" is the unsaid person/subject. The person arriving first is being served first. The person first arriving is not going the first to serve. It's not tennis.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The second is correct.  It is a form of "Those who come first are served first."

Comment: I don't think that's a great explanation; I mean, the phrase is also a form of "He who comes first is served first", but we don't say \*"First comes, first served." The key is that *come* and *served* are both past-participle forms; I think the original full form was something more like "He who is first come, is first served", or more briefly "First come is first served." Since we no longer use *to be come* that way (we now say *to **have** come*), that parallelism was lost, which I guess explains the modern variant with bare *serve*.

Comment: @ruakh: Very well said.

Answer (score 4):

As I have always been under the impression it is the former "First come, first serve", I have just google-searched the phrase.

The search returns most results confirming @Michael Blaustein's answer, with websites like Wikipedia containing the phrase "First Come, First Served" and so it seems this is the correct, original form.

You can also notice a few entries using "First come, first serve" (without the 'd') on forums and in newspaper articles and titles which suggests, as I have come to know, this version is also commonly used.

Comment: Yes, 'first serve' is common; because the phrase is commonly misunderstood.  Congratulations on becoming *one who knows the difference*! ;-)